# jQuery not able to update my global variable

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a function, for navigating between tabs, and also submits a form. The back-end validation is working just as expected, but i'm setting my global variable isValid=false if the user gave invalid input. I'm only validating one form for now, hence the use of data.isValid.

**My Jquery Code**

```
var tabID, relatedTabID, isValid=true;

$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var formData = $('#form').serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/roa',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {inputs: formData, nextTab: relatedTabID, currentTab: tabID}, //also need to pass in related Tab ID, and also tabID
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.value===1){
                if (data.isValid){//if data is valid, return next view
                    $('#tabShow').html((data.view));
                    isValid=true;
                }
                else{//if it isn't target the div id=erros and replace only error section

                    isValid=false;
                    var x=jQuery.parseJSON(data.msg);
                    var errorString = '';
                    $.each( x.errors, function( key, value) {
                        errorString += "<li class='alert alert-danger'>" + value + '</li>';
                    });
                    alert(errorString);
                    $('.something').html(errorString);
                    return false;//prevent navigation
                }
            }
            else{
            $('#tabShow').html((data.view));}
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('hide.bs.tab', '.nav-pills a', function (e) {

    tabID = $(e.target).attr('id');
    relatedTabID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');
    $('#form').submit();
    alert(isValid);
    if (tabID==='section2'){
        return false;
    }

});
```

My function $(document).on('hide.bs.tab', '.nav-pills a', function (e) is not able to detect the change in my global variable isValid. I don't really understand the problem here.

**My back-end code**

```
Route::post('/roa', function() {
$m = Request::except('_token');
$name = "form1_sections/" . $m['nextTab'] . "_form";//next view name
$name2 = "form1_sections/" . $m['currentTab'] . "_form";//current view name

parse_str($m['inputs'], $output);
$type= gettype($output);
if ($m['currentTab']=='section2'){//only validation for section2
    $rules = [
        'TB1_course.*' => 'required'
    ];
    $validator=Validator::make($output, $rules);
    if ($validator->passes()){
        return ["view" => view("$name")-> render(), "value"=>1, "type"=>$type, "isValid"=>true];
    }
    return ["view" => view("$name2")->withErrors($validator) -> render(), "value"=>1, "type"=>$type, "isValid"=>false, "msg"=>json_encode([
        'errors' => $validator->errors()->getMessages(),
        'code' => 422
     ])];
}
return ["view" => view("$name") -> render()];
});
```

Even when an error is detected, it should return a value of false. I would like to stop navigation if validation is incorrect. An interesting thing to note is that isValid returns true, even when I display the errors but after that if I try navigating somewhere else, it returns false. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your else was triggered? if yes you might want to do this for your Global variables declare an object and access it.

ex

```
var Global = {
     isValid = true
///put all your Global variable here
}
```

then access it using the Global object your problem might be the scoping in js

```
Global.isValid = false;
```

Comment: Yea my else statement is triggered but after the alert(isValid). If I alert something in the else statement (it first alerts(isValid)) and then the alert inside the else statement, whereas it should do opposite. I read somewhere that it is because of jquery doesn't do ajax in a chronological order. But I have no idea how to fix this issue.